# Java logging export using fluentd

Tags: java, log4j, jetty, fluentd

We are streaming Jetty server logs to stackdriver using google-fluentd. The issue I'm having is that fluentd is treating each line in the log as a separate log entry. This is problematic for log analysis later.

I've tried a few `format multiline` patterns but they're not very reliable, there are quite a few edge cases to handle (exception stacktrace, etc). I think it would be best to just replace all newlines with "\n" within the same log entry, which would solve the issue. I can always replace "\n" later to make it more readable.

I couldn't find log4j property that does this... anyone knows which setting I need to tweak?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not log4j, and it likely never will be.

Its configured with `java.util.logging` on gcloud, but as a system logger (not application controled), with limited ability to configure it (only system properties).

There's [a pull request with Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime/pull/295) that fixes some of the issues surrounding it, but generally speaking its not meant to be configured by the application.

> Note: in the future the connection between the application and the fluentd will be a formal non-logging API.